# Select SQL query returning only one value of array in the tableModel

Tags: java, tablemodel

I'm trying to fetch rows with commodities under a similar category name from a particular `categories` table in a database and, with each of the rows, I have made a second SQL query to do summation of quantities of orders made in the past one week from the `orders table`. I want the results to be added to a table model, but only one row is added.

```
private void analyticsTableQuery(String Category) {
    this.categorySelected = Category;
    categoryTitle.setText(Category);
   int ordered;
    int initial;
    String query2 = "SELECT * FROM stock INNER JOIN category ON stock.Category_id=category.id where category.Category_Name='"+Category+"'";
    try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://194.5.156.94:3306/u843360242_tukule?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC","u843360242_tukule","cocaine");
            pst = con.prepareStatement(query2);
            rs=pst.executeQuery();
            DefaultTableModel tm=(DefaultTableModel)analyticsTable.getModel();
            tm.setRowCount(0);
         while(rs.next()){
                int id = rs.getInt("stock.id");
                int current = rs.getInt("stock.Quantity");
                String name = rs.getString("stock.Name");
                String price = rs.getString("stock.Price");
                String query = "SELECT sum(Quantity) as 'sum' FROM `orders` WHERE Created_at >= DATE(CURRENT_DATE() -7) 
                and Stock_id ="+id; 
                try {
               con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/u843360242_tukule 
         useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC","root","");
               pst = con.prepareStatement(query);
               rs=pst.executeQuery();
               rs.next();
                   if(rs.getInt("sum") > 0)
                {
                  ordered = rs.getInt("sum");
                  initial = current + ordered;
                }
                else{ 
                  ordered = 0;
                  initial = current + ordered;
                }
                   Object o[]={
                            name,
                            price,
                            initial};
                   tm.addRow(o); 
               } catch (SQLException ex) {
                   Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
               }     
           }             
     } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Login.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     }  
}
```

Comment: Your connection, statement, and result-set (`con`, `pst`, and `rs`) are "re-written" inside the `while(rs.next())` loop.  Is that intentional?

Comment: yes. it works just fine with that normally as long as its in a separate try block.

Comment:  Ok, wasn't sure about the scoping

Comment: I think its just a slight logic problem but i don't see where

Comment: Ahh, so it *was* because `rs` was being reinitialized ("rewritten")....  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using resultset `rs` for both outer and inner results.
re-initializing `rs` with inner resultset affects your outer loop condition.
And even if there are still rows in `rs` due to which loop progresses, reading columns like `id, quantity, name` etc will result in exception as there columns might not be present in the new resultset `rs`.

Comment: Thank you @Codeek. The resultSet variable re-initializing in second query is what affected it thanks a lot.

Comment: @Mariwa, well you could always upvote and mark it as answer, just saying :P